# Misunderstanding of \PassOptionsToPackage?

Tags: package-options

In the following code I would like to use `\PassOptionsToPackage` but this does not work. What am I doing wrong ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{algorithm2e}
\PassOptionsToPackage{french}{algorithm2e}
\PassOptionsToPackage{vlined}{algorithm2e}

% \RequirePackage[french, vlined]{algorithm2e} % <-- This works.

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \Switch{X}{
        \Case{1}{A}
        \Other{Other}
    }
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

PS: concretly I use a script to automate the imports of package that I need so I can use the working solution but I still want to understand what makes the things going wrong.

Comment: you are passing the options after the package has already finished, so they are never processed.

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstand the logic of the macro.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle For future reference, your comment beat my answer by two minutes. The karma is yours by right.

Comment: @Davislor no problem:-) (and you added the extra global option hint)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put `\PassOptionsToPackage` *before* you load the package.  It modifies how the package will be loaded in the future.

In this case, you might not need it.  Language options normally belong in the `\documentclass`, which passes them to all packages.  In most cases, the way to resolve an option class to a package loaded indirectly is to load it directly first.  What is the situation that prevents you from simply loading the options the normal way?

Comment: I use a very uggly Python script that analyses several sty files and gather them in a single sty file : [the file](https://github.com/typensee-latex/tnsproba/blob/master/factory/build-02-sty.py) . The script works stupidly because I am lazzy man :-))